Schema Mismatch Spark to BigQuery: Having problems with ArrayType() fields
I am trying to do a project that I am getting data from an api source and sending it to my kafka with a producer real time. Then I am trying to read the data and stream write it to my table in BigQuery. I get problems with the genres field and the same error as any other ArrayType() fields. How can I change the schema or do any processing to be able to write the data as an array of objects?
I am using RAWG game API as my data source.
I get this error when I try to write my df to my BigQuery Table under my dataset:
Schema mismatch: referenced variable 'genres.list.element.slug' has array levels of 1, while the corresponding field path to Parquet column has 0 repeated fields

I have my schema here:
game_schema = StructType([
        StructField("slug", StringType(), True),
        StructField("name", StringType(), True),
        StructField("playtime", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("platforms", ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField("platform", StructType([
                        StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
                        StructField("name", StringType(), True),
                        StructField("slug", StringType(), True)
                ]), True)
        ])), True),
        StructField("stores", ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField("store", StructType([
                        StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
                        StructField("name", StringType(), True),
                        StructField("slug", StringType(), True)
                ]), True)
        ])), True),
        StructField("released", DateType(), True),
        StructField("tba", BooleanType(), True),
        StructField("background_image", StringType(), True),
        StructField("rating", DoubleType(), True),
        StructField("rating_top", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("ratings", ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("title", StringType(), True),
                StructField("count", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("percent", DoubleType(), True)
        ])), True),
        StructField("ratings_count", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("reviews_text_count", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("added", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("added_by_status", StructType([
                StructField("yet", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("owned", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("beaten", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("toplay", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("dropped", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("playing", IntegerType(), True)
        ]), True),
        StructField("metacritic", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("suggestions_count", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("updated", TimestampType(), True),
        StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("tags", ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("name", StringType(), True),
                StructField("slug", StringType(), True),
                StructField("language", StringType(), True),
                StructField("games_count", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("image_background", StringType(), True)
        ])), True),
        StructField("esrb_rating", StructType([
                StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("name", StringType(), True),
                StructField("slug", StringType(), True),
                StructField("name_en", StringType(), True),
                StructField("name_ru", StringType(), True)
        ]), True),
        StructField("reviews_count", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("saturated_color", StringType(), True),
        StructField("dominant_color", StringType(), True),
        StructField("short_screenshots", ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("image", StringType(), True)
        ])), True),
        StructField("parent_platforms", ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField("platform", StructType([
                        StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
                        StructField("name", StringType(), True),
                        StructField("slug", StringType(), True)
                ]), True)
        ])), True),
        StructField("genres", ArrayType(
            StructType([
                StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("name", StringType(), True),
                StructField("slug", StringType(), True)
        ])), True)
])

I tried flattening it and only getting the id of the genres separated by a comma in string format. But I need them as an array of integers so I can join the genres table that I have to see the matching genres by each game. (A game can have multiple genres)
